# Estimation of panel data

Tags: regression, panel-data, generalized-moments, plm

I am estimating the effect of certain bank characteristics on the bank lending in monetary policy in the euro area. Therefore I am looking at different bank characteristics (size, liquidity and capitalization), the evolution of net loans and some control variables like GDP and inflation for the euro zone. This is my regression equation:
[image]

I am using Panel data since I have quarterly data for every bank I am looking at. My question is: how would you start estimating? So far, I have used panel data regression in R with pooled and fixed effects models, like the following example:

```
    ## Fixed effects
# Factor size
MOD_FE_9 <- plm(x ~ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + MP_1 + MP_2 + MP_3 + MP_4 + M_S_1 + 
                  M_S_2 + M_S_3 + M_S_4 + size + HICP_1 + HICP_2 + HICP_3 + 
                  HICP_4 + GDP_1 + GDP_2 + GDP_3 + GDP_4, data = df, 
                model = "within", effect = "twoways")
    summary(MOD_FE_9)
```

At first I even tried the GMM estimation technique -  however this was more than just complicated. Am I on the right path with the plm function or would you do anything differently? This is how you analyse Panel Data right? And I am right that for the gmm method, I have to create 21 moment functions since I am estimating 21 parameters? Furthermore, I decided to go for the fixed model because the F-test always shows a small p-value.